# Docker container is running, but its process has finished

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I run my typescript application in a docker container. Sometimes it happens, that the application finishes, but the container is still in the running state. How is this even possible ? I was thinking that I forgot to catch a rejected Promise or forgot to close a stream, but in that case, `docker top myContainer` would say me, that the main process is still running, right ?

Docker ps:

```
docker ps
5c63b442af79        filipxxx/v2x_communication   "npm run start ether…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours        vehicle2
```

Docker top:

```
docker top vehicle2
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME
```

Docker inspect:

```
docker inspect vehicle2
[
    {
        "Id": "5c63b442af799b8ff3b83d7c53e1ccfd2a290d469b58b10970217aa987e963f9",
        "Created": "2019-01-03T13:26:50.947651153Z",
        "Path": "npm",
        "Args": [
            "run",
            "start",
            "ethereum",
            "172.21.0.3:8545",
            "run-producer",
            "2",
            "100",
            "0xfb69fd63952d243fc235b91ff7bc49f9cd4a31f8"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 46799,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-01-03T13:33:52.860979672Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
...
```

Surprisingly when running `docker exec -i vehicle2 echo 'hello world'`, it returns me: `cannot exec in a stopped state: unknown`.

Below is the dockerfile, I used to build the image.

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /v2x_communication
COPY . /v2x_communication

RUN npm install && npm run build

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
```

Even if I run docker stop vehicle2, it exits successfully, but the vehicle2 is still listed under `docker ps` and `docker inspect vehicle2` is still saying that its in the running state.

**Docker info:**

```
Containers: 50
 Running: 48
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 150
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: sah8xlcjnxbq13uofznqrjs6e
 Is Manager: false
 Node Address: 10.132.0.5
 Manager Addresses:
  10.132.0.2:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: c4446665cb9c30056f4998ed953e6d4ff22c7c39
runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1026-gcp
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 48
Total Memory: 94.41GiB
Name: vehicle-fleet-big-1
ID: OAVG:6QVR:EH3F:OYNO:ADC4:QDAN:R2AF:LSSV:2VSI:IJWJ:PJH2:LJVP
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Comment: Please update your question with `docker info` and `docker top $container_id` of the problem container.

Comment: @BMitch: updated!

Answer (score 4):

Either you've found a bug, or something is holding the container open. The closest issue I can find is rather old [#30927](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30927). I'd start investigating dockerd and OS logs to see if there are any errors you can find there. For dockerd, that's in `journalctl -u docker` for systemd environments. And on the OS, anything under /var/log for would be good to start debugging. Potential blockers I can imagine include:

- a failed shim process, perhaps a runc stuck in a zombie state
- a mount that will not release, something could be trying to read files in the docker filesystem
- commands querying the container that haven't exited, perhaps something pulling lots of logs that has hung waiting for a pipe / buffer to clear

If you can't find anything, an issue in the moby/moby repo may be appropriate, but without any logs of an error pointing back to why, or a way to reproduce, it will be difficult to fix.

Comment: I have opened a new issue here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/38501